# How to use Uniswap UniversalRouter

Tags: uniswap, defi

I want to use UniversalRouter to do swap, and the function supplied in UniswapRouter smart contract is here.

```
function execute(bytes calldata commands, bytes[] calldata inputs, uint256 deadline)
    external
    payable
    checkDeadline(deadline)
{
    execute(commands, inputs);
}
```

here is a transation example in Arbiscan

```
Function: execute(bytes commands,bytes[] inputs,uint256 deadline)

MethodID: 0x3593564c
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060
[1]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
[2]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063fdeb90
[3]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
[4]:  0b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[5]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
[6]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
[7]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
[8]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
[9]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
[10]: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000aa87bee538000
[11]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
[12]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
[13]: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000aa87bee538000
[14]: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000eb08bf1ab3308a
[15]: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
[16]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[17]: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b
[18]: 82af49447d8a07e3bd95bd0d56f35241523fbab1000bb8fc5a1a6eb076a2c7ad
[19]: 06ed22c90d7e710e35ad0a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to know how can i construct the arguments of commands and inputs so that i can use the function. Are there any public implementations to refer to? I need help in this problem, please.
Related link: code
https://github.com/Uniswap/universal-router/blob/main/contracts/UniversalRouter.sol

transaction
https://arbiscan.io/tx/0xb1151d16a8dd84696ec81f9c9c61ec9aa8759099ae51765ba9877ee2313c897f

Comment: I'm trying to work out the exact same thing, it will come down to correctly encoding the arguments into bytes. In the meantime it might help to look at how this repo manages the encoding: https://github.com/Elnaril/uniswap-universal-router-decoder